# Jest test redux action with thunk doesn't cover statemets

Tags: unit-testing, redux, enzyme, jestjs, redux-thunk

Hello i have been trying to test a function with thunk and all the test passes but can't figure it out why the coverage doesn't not update or the test function does not cover the statement.

This is my function:

```
export const setFinished = (campaignId, userId, actionId, callback) => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        await axios.post(`http://bazuca.com:9000/campaigns/${campaignId}/progress`, {
            userId,
            actionId
        }, { headers: { token: getState().app.token } })
            .then((response) => {

            })
            .catch((error) => {

            })

        callback();
    }
}
```

This is my ***last*** test (I have done like 3 different types and cant get the coverage to work)

```
describe("setFinished", () => {

    it("works", () => {
        const dispatch = jest.fn();
        const callback = jest.fn(() => 'callback');
        const getState = jest.fn();
        let a = setFinished(1, 1, 1, callback)
        expect(a).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 1, 1, callback);
        a(dispatch, getState);
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

and i just get this in the coverage:
 [image]

Maybe im doing it wrong? or should use another library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some things missing in your test setup. Especially the way you're making an assertion about the dispatch mock looks unusual. Without going into too much detail, just consider the following:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { setFinished } from 'path/to/your/actions';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('setFinished', () => {
    it('works', () => {
        // You have to make sure axios calls are mocked out properly
        // at this point. I don't have a snippet handy for this so I
        // left it out. But it would be similar to the following:
        axios.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
            // Let the promise return whatever your response is for a
            // positive test case
            post: () => Promise.resolve({ isFinished: true })
        }));

        const expected = [
            // I'm assuming something like this is dispatched in the
            // .then handler of your action:
            { type: 'SET_FINISHED_SUCCESS' }
        ];

        const store = mockStore({});

        // Mock some arguments here
        return store.dispatch(setFinished(1, 2, 3, () => null))
            .then(() => expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expected));
    });
});
```

If axios is mocked out correctly, this will definitely achieve 100% coverage for this action if you also add a negative test case for the catch block.